# How to get google map location coordinates in django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, google-maps, django-admin

I'm implementing a website in django that stores information about various places. I want a functionality in django-admin to select(tap) a location on google map and store it in my database so that I can display my places on google map when required.

What are various ways to do it in Django?

Comment: I think you'll want to check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ (The Google Maps API - javascript)

Answer (score 6):

Better late than never...
Try [django-geoposition](http://django-geoposition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: To install the current github version (0.2) through pip, (extremely usefull if you are running on python 3, while pypi has currently available the version 0.1.5) you can issue the following command:

```pip install git+https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition.git@master```

It works great on django 1.6.1 and python 3.3.2